# In PYTHON, how to access a CSV cell using multiple column indexing by value?

Tags: python, csv

For example, let's say this is 'my.CSV':

```
bus,seat,value
--------------
001,0009,0.012
001,0099,0.013
001,0999,0.014
002,0009,0.031
002,0099,0.032
002,0999,0.033
...
```

It is about 1GB, so relatively large and my code base is in Python

I need to define the following function

```
def get_value(bus, seat):
    # FILL CODE HERE
    return value
```

When called,

```
v = get_value(1,9)
print(v)
```

the output will be:

```
0.012
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: use pandas? it's the standard for python

Comment: How would you do that with Pandas?

Answer (score 1):

1GB is large, but usually still fits in memory. so if you need to read many values, reading it to memory is probably a good solution.

if this is indeed the usage pattern, I would read the file into a hash with (bus,seat) as the keys, and value as the value

sample code (untested):

```
import csv
data = {}
with open('my.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            data[(row[0],row[1)] = row[2]

def get_value(data,bus,seat)
    return data[(bus,seat)]
```

Answer (score 0):

if everything still fits into memory, you could construct a dictionary from all your data like this:

```
from csv import reader
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(dict)

with open('file.csv', 'rb') as in_file:
    csv_data = reader(in_file)
    for row in csv_data:
        data[int(row[0])][int(row[1])] = float(row[2])

print(data[1][9])  # 0.012
```

Comment: Thanks, this does it. The int() and float() casts were necessary.
What if the file would NOT fit in memory, for whatever reason?

Comment: then you'd probably have to start thinking about a database. a key-value store might be enough. there are several options available... this may help: https://www.fullstackpython.com/no-sql-datastore.html (they suggest `redis` or `memcached`). maybe there are simpler options...

Comment: by the way: python 3.6 massively improved memory use for dictionaries... if you get to choose the interpreter that may be worth it!

Comment: oopos. both `redis` and `memcached` seems to be in-memory. so they will not help...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the network approach using networkx package. If your data.txt is:

```
001,0009,0.012
001,0099,0.013
001,0999,0.014
002,0009,0.031
002,0099,0.032
002,0999,0.033
...
```

You could do

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_weighted_edgelist('data.txt', delimiter=',')
```

`G` Is now a hashable object, so that

```
G['001']['0009']
```

outputs the dictionary

```
{'weight': 0.012}
```

`networkx` is used to my knowledge for extensive databases, so it may work fine for yours.